# Как сделать выбор нескольких файлов за раз для загрузки со смартфона через форму

Tags: html, input, multiple

Сделал html форму с input multiple, на компе работает выбор нескольких файлов, а на андроиде только по 1 файлу.

Как сделать чтобы в 1 инпут можно было несколько файлов выбрать?

Вижу что не поддерживает андроид аттрибут multiple, как быть тогда, делать несколько полей?

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple

Comment: В Chrome для android это работает, вас не устраивает?

Comment: @Mr_Epic у меня не работает в хроме с андроида, по ссылке что я дал - там частично поддерживается только в хроме 57, а в остальных браузерах - нет.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple

Comment: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="file" multiple>` [**не поддерживается**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348912) на Android-устройстве.

Имейте в виду, что  предназначен только для html5. Он просто вернется к одному файлу в старых браузерах.
Вы можете попробовать указать имя в виде массива: name = "file[]". Он не нужен по спецификации, но может помочь ...
Попробуйте также сделать считывание на консоли переменной «file []».

пример некого рабочего кода:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' action='submitForm.php'> 
    <input type='file' name='files[]' ng-model='attachFiles' onchange='angular.element(this).scope().onFileSystemChange(this)' accept='image/*,video/*' multiple />
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```